# Expected Profit from a Lottery Ticket

Tags: probability

> Ahmed is playing a lottery game where he must pick 2 numbers from 0 to
>   9 and then one letter out of the 26-letter English alphabet. He may
>   choose the same number both times. If his ticket matches the 2 numbers
>   and 1 letter drawn in order, he wins the grand prize and receives
>   \$10,405.
>
> If just his letter matches but one or both of his numbers do not
>   match, he wins the small prize of \$100. Under any other outcome he
>   loses and receives nothing. The game costs him \$5 to play. He has
>   chosen the ticket 04R. Assuming that he paid the \$5 and he picked the
>   ticket 04R.

The solution to the problem is found in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vlBOHckmzU&feature=youtu.be

In the video, the probability of getting the small prize is (1/26) - (1/2600). Shouldn't the probability of winning the small prize be the sum of the probabilities of getting the letter right and 1 number wrong + getting the letter right and 2 numbers wrong: (1/26)*(9/10)*(1/10) + (1/26)*(9/10)*(9/10)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability of getting one letter right and 1 number wrong isn't $\frac{1}{26}\cdot\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{10}$, it's twice this. After this fix both answers are the same.

It can be easier to see in smaller and simpler problem. For example, if you toss two biased coins with probability of head $\frac{1}{3}$ and of tail $\frac{2}{3}$, probability of getting one head and one tail isn't $\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3}$ - it's probability of, say, "the first coin lands head, the second lands tail" (A), or vice versa (B). And the event "one coin lands head, one coin lands tail" is (disjoint) union of (A) and (B) - so it's probability is sum of probabilities of (A) and (B).

Comment: Ahhh yes! Thank you very much! Could you explain the reasoning behind (1/26) - (1/2600) though? I understand why you'd have to subtract 1/2600 but why does 1/26 by itself work? 1/26 in itself means the probability of getting the letter right but it does not include the probability of getting the numbers wrong, does it? If 1/26 in itself works then how come when I encounter questions like "what's the probability of scoring 3/5 free throws" I have to multiply the probability of successful free throws WITH the probability of the misses?

Comment: Probability of getting letter right is sum of probabilities of (get letter right, get numbers right) and (get letter right, get at least number wrong), so probability of getting letter right and at least one number wrong is (probability of getting letter right) - (probability of getting letter right and at least one number wrong).

Comment: sorry for the trouble but could you help me with my most recent question... it's pertaining to this topic...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you are missing something. Can you figure it out?

$$2\cdot \frac{1}{26}\frac{1}{9}\frac{1}{10} +  \frac{1}{26}\frac{9}{10} \frac{9}{10} $$

Comment: Thank you very much!!!